# Are values valid JSON responses in solo?

Tags: json

Is sending values i.e. `54`, `'foobar'`, `true` considered as valid JSON response, or do I have to wrap them into objects, i.e. `{ result: 54 }`, `{ result: 'foobar' }` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The {} is necessary, and MUST contain at least one name-value pair. See http://www.json.org/ for JSON syntax.

Comment: OK, but I did not mention `{}`. I asked about `54` and stuff.

Comment: What I meant was, that for it to be considered JSON, it MUST start with { and end with }. Whether it will work without them depends completely on the code that is going to parse the JSON object. If you are the only user, you can do what you want. But it won't really be JSON.

Comment: This is not strictly true.  Array structures are valid JSON.  Also why does JSON.parse(54) work?